# android - how can I make this MediaStore code work below API 11?

Tags: android, compatibility, android-2.2-froyo, mediastore

I've been working on some code to gather image and video thumbnails and load them in a cursor.

So far, I have this:

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE };
String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
+ MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE + " OR "
+ MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
+ MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, queryUri,
                                projection, selection, null,
                                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED
                                + " DESC");
Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
```

Unfortunately, it only works on API 11 and up. How can I change it to make it work with API 8?

**EDIT:** I'm using support CursorLoader, the MediaStore functions are creating the problems.

MediaStore.Files.FileColumns needs API 11, is there an alternative?

Comment: Be more precise, which part is not working? Maybe, post your logcat message.

Comment: Added some stuff, sorry, I'm new to this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I /think/ I understand what you're trying to do.

Unfortunately, FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE and such functions can only be used in APIs 11 and up. I suggest you create a seperate function for APIs less than 11:

```
        if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        String[] from = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE };
        projection = from;
        String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE + " OR "
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
        Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, queryUri, projection,
                selection, null, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED
                        + " DESC");
    } else {
        String[] from = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED };
        projection = from;
        cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, sourceUri, null, null, null,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " desc");
    }
    Cursor cursor = null;
    if (cursorLoader != null) {
        cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
            }
```

This function **will not find video thumbnails for API<11**, instead finding thumbnails for only images. I'm not sure on how one could put video and image thumbnails together using this method.

Comment: Thanks. If anybody can find out how to put two cursors together, I'd be greatful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [android.support.v4.CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/CursorLoader.html) from [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Edit:

`FileColumns` extend `MediaColumns`, so use `MediaColumns` instead.
For uri, you should choose the Uri based on what are you trying to query. If it's images, use `Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, for audio, use `Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, etc.

Comment: The problem is with MediaStore, I'm afraid :/ Thanks anyway.